# My button doesn't change function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering why the button doesn't change to the other function where the button will turn red when clicking it a second time.

My goal is to have one button that will change function depending on whether you pressed it once

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #hello {
           padding: 30px 60px;
           background-color: #4db8ff;
           width: 100px;
           text-align: center;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           cursor: pointer;
           color: white;
           font-family: arial;
           font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hello" onclick="button()">START</div>
</body>
<script>

    var x = true;

    if(x == true) {
        function button() {
            x = false;
            alert("once");
        }
    }
    
    if(x == false) {
        function button() {
            alert("twice");
            document.getElementById("hello").style.background = "#ff3333";
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're conditionally creating, on page load, one of two possible function definitions. The second definition won't replace the first just because you've reassigned the boolean flag at some point.

Create a single function that checks the status of `x` internally:

```
function button() {
    if(x) { // Comparing against true is redundant
        x = false;
        alert("once");

    } else {
        alert("twice");
        document.getElementById("hello").style.background = "#ff3333";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a thought dough, what does it mean when you put an x/variable alone like that ?

Comment: @Simon All `if` is checking is if what it was given can be considered "true". When you wrote `x == true`, that returns either `true` or `false`. `x` alone is already equal to `true` or `false` though, so you don't need the `== true` part.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Simon No problem. Make sure you truly understand the condition to `if`, `while` and other constructs though, and how they use the values that you give them. You will be using them constantly, so it's important to have a good understanding of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `button()` is only being defined once. You can not define a function based on a condition, it will be defined as soon as its surrounding code is executed. Thus, you need to place your `if` statements inside the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #hello {
           padding: 30px 60px;
           background-color: #4db8ff;
           width: 100px;
           text-align: center;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           cursor: pointer;
           color: white;
           font-family: arial;
           font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hello" onclick="button()">START</div>
</body>
<script>

    var x = true;
function button(){
    if(x) {
            x = false;
            alert("once");
    } else {
            alert("twice");
            document.getElementById("hello").style.background = "#ff3333";
    }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses. I make sure to add it to my project

Comment: @Simon No problem.